# indexOf() == -1 doesn't seem to work when pushing to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array which is filtered/searched when I type into the input box. When I hit return the input text is appended to the array. This is all great and it works.

What is not working is the $scope.list.indexOf() == -1 which is supposed to stop me entering duplicates. But it does not work.

Where am I going wrong?

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="bgApp">
<head>
<title>List & Tag</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Local CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="./static/css/dev-style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="listController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-title">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <h1><small>{{title}}</small></h1>
                <input type="text" ng-enter="addItem()" ng-model="addName" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-title">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">Name of Item</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 div-row" ng-repeat="item in list | filter:addName">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">{{ item.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




<!-- AngularJS scripts from CDN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<!-- JQuery scripts from CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap scripts compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Locally installed scripts --> 
<script src="./js/bgapp.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The APP, Directive & Controller

```
var bgapp = angular.module('bgApp', [])

.directive('ngEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter, {
                        'event': event
                    });
                });

                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});

bgapp.controller('listController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.title = 'Recent Activity';

    $scope.list = [
        {name: 'User 1'},
        {name: 'Admin 1'},
        {name: 'Service 1'},
        {name: 'Project 1'},
        {name: 'Configuration Item 1'},
        {name: 'Task 1'},
        {name: 'Incident 1'},
        {name: 'Issue 1'},
        {name: 'Known Issue 1'},
        {name: 'Problem 1'},
        {name: 'Knowledge Base 1'},
        {name: 'Update 1'},
        {name: 'Document 1'},
        ];

    $scope.addItem = function() {
        var elem = {name: $scope.addName};
        if ($scope.list.indexOf(elem) == -1) {
            $scope.list.push(
                elem
            );
        }    
    };

}]);
```

Comment: In the example the "if" statement checks to see if what I have typed exists in the array. If it does not exist then -1 is true and the push will happen.Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: This is a classic example of `{} !== {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$scope.list` is a list of `Object`, testing `$scope.list.indexOf(elem)` works with the references of the 2 `Object`s, which are always differents.

You could use `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)` from [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    var elem = {name: $scope.addName};
    if ($filter('filter')($scope.list, {name: elem.name}).length == 0) {
        $scope.list.push(
            elem
        );
    }    
};
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer. This worked for me straight out of the box without me needing to think about it.  Thank you all for commenting, I appreciate the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not consider the objects to be equal because they are not the same instance.  [This link](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/finding-array-elements-with-array-indexof.html) explains nicely.

I would suggest using underscore's findWhere to test if an object with the same properties exists.

In your case:

```
if (_.findWhere($scope.list, elem) === undefined){
   $scope.list.push(elem);
}
```

You will, of course, need to include underscore to use it.  Since you're using angular, you may want to use this:

https://github.com/floydsoft/angular-underscore

Answer (score 0):

Away from a computer so I'm taking a stab, but it seems like you're trying to perform a string op on an object (list of items).

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    var elem = {name: $scope.addName};
    if ($scope.listHasElement($scope.list, elem)) {
        $scope.list.push(elem);
    }    
};

$scope.listHasElement = function (list, new) {
    for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
        if(list[index].name == new.name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Try this, i am not able to test it right now but i guess its the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your current `indexOf` is failing because no two objects are the same unless they're the same reference, i.e. `{} !== {}` but `var o = {}; o === o;`

As you're trying to find a reference, know how the object was created originally and your *Object* can be serialised into JSON without throwing an error you could use that last point to perform an `indexOf` for *Strings* instead

For example, making use of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
function serialisedIndexOf(haystack, needle) {
    return haystack.map(JSON.stringify).indexOf(JSON.stringify(needle));
}

var arr = [[1], [2], [3]];
serialisedIndexOf(
    arr,
    [2]
); // 1
// so the original reference for [2] can be obtained at arr[1]
```

---

You can similarly use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which can end on the first match (vs the `.map` above which will always go through every item in the array at least once) but requires a little more code to achieve

```
function serialisedIndexOf(haystack, needle) {
    var i, r;
    needle = JSON.stringify(needle);
    r = haystack.some(function (e, idx) {
        i = idx;
        return JSON.stringify(e) === needle;
    });
    return r ? i : -1;
}
```

---

In *ES6* we will have [`Array.prototype.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) which can give us a shorter version of the `.some` method, but you shouldn't assume browser support for this yet

```
function serialisedIndexOf(haystack, needle) {
    needle = JSON.stringify(needle);
    return haystack.findIndex(function (e) {
        return JSON.stringify(e) === needle;
    });
}
```